# Plotly Express Update On Click to filter Dataframe filter

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to link a click on the plotly express tree map to a filter on the data frame. So when a user clicks on a country on the graph, the dataframe will filter for the specific country instead of showing all

There is "Update points using a click callback" for plotly.graph_objects but I am not sure how to make it work for plotly express.

```
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
df["world"] = "world" # in order to have a single root node
fig = px.treemap(df, path=['world', 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
               color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
               color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
               color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))
fig.show()
## when user clicks on a country in the tree-map, the get_data function filters the df and outputs specific data on the country 

def get_data(df, click):
    return df[df['country'] == click]

get_data(df,click)
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a few tricks:

- Convert the output of plotly express to a `FigureWidget` with `data` and `layout` attributes. This enables us to add a callback.
- Use a display handle `dh` **with a `display_id`** to update the showed dataframe.
- Use `display(fig)` instead of `fig.show()`, in order to invoke the callbacks on the widget.

I also marked `filtered_df` as global in order to have it available for inspection, but if you just want to display it that is not necessary.

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from IPython.display import display

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
df["world"] = "world"  # in order to have a single root node


def filter_country(trace, points, state):
    global filtered_df
    region = trace.labels[points.point_inds[0]]
    filtered_df = df[(df["country"] == region) | (df["continent"] == region)]

    dh.update(filtered_df)


fig = px.treemap(
    df,
    path=["world", "continent", "country"],
    values="pop",
    color="lifeExp",
    hover_data=["iso_alpha"],
    color_continuous_scale="RdBu",
    color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df["lifeExp"], weights=df["pop"]),
)

fig = go.FigureWidget(fig.data, fig.layout)

fig.data[0].on_click(filter_country)

display(fig)
dh = display(display_id=True)
```

Reference:

- https://plotly.com/python/click-events/
- https://mindtrove.info/jupyter-tidbit-display-handles/